# Problema ao instalar imagem docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

Estou realizando a instalação de uma imagem do container: microsoft/windowsservercore

Estou usando o seguinte comando para baixar e instalar a imagem:

```
docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

Porém ele não finaliza a instalação. Depois de algumas horas baixando e extraindo o pacote tenho o erro:

> failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\978c7311a5583355b609861f00632bc14551d23ab5cbc711d0304a009156e1cb: Esta operação foi retornada porque o tempo limite expirou.

Estou usando a seguinte versão do docker:

```
PS C:\Users\gfrancisco> docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:21:42 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Como posso fazer para instalar essa imagem?

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou executar o comando:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windowsservercore-insider:latest
```

Fonte: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore-insider/

Lembrando de que o docker deve estar instalado seguindo os passos do site do [docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/).

E também caso não consiga e o problema persistir tente executar os comandos via o [DockerToolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/), trata-se de um terminal exclusivo *docker*, ja passei por algumas situações onde o cmd do windows não atendeu as minhas necessidades para com a utilização do *docker*.